# Problem with flutter Bloc rebuild/listening/re-drawing "trigger"

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc

Im trying to change a value using the `state is XX` techniche, though flutter doesnt listen to stream or maybe no redrawing is triggerd

```dart
class AnimatedBox extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _animatedBoxBloc = BlocProvider.of<AnimatedboxBloc>(context);
    return BlocBuilder(
      bloc: _animatedBoxBloc,
      builder: (context, state) {
        return AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          curve: Curves.easeIn,
          width: 200.0,
          height: 200.0,
          color:
          state is YellowAnimatedboxState ? Colors.yellow :
          state is BlueAnimatedboxState ? Colors.blue :
          Colors.transparent,
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

i know that using that method can be applied but when it's applied at the return of the builder i.e Blocbuilder .. if (state is A) return , if (state is B) return ; and then the builder return and entirly new build.
but, i only need to change a VALUE and i want to change it via Bloc pattern.
is it even possible? maybe im doing it wrong or the changed value need to be in the state that changes.
by that i mean write the bloc with these properties:
... extends

Comment: If you only need to change a value, so don't use event-state builder. Event-State is not canonical for BLoC, use it when you need, no need to overkill. So, just create a StreamBuilder and connect it with the stream that holds the value you need, thats all.

Comment: well im trying to learn how to implement bloc for the first time so i just it doesnt bother me... also isnt StreamBuilder would achive the same result in the same way as bloc?

Comment: Of course, you'll get same result. BlocBuilder created just for handling states, if you don't have event-state transitions, no need for it.